# SharePoint Workflow missing action "send document set to repository"

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to create a 2010 workflow and use the "send document set to repository" action.
But it is missing. 
I'm trying to utilize the "send to..." to move a Document set in SharePoint online.

Comment: I have encountered the same conditions with SharePoint online. It does appear in the on-premises version. The only way I can move documents across sites and collections in the online SharePoint is via the Content Organizer.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for the [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) site.